# Redirecting in flow without code

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, flow, urlfor

I am trying to redirect my flow back to a standard page using this

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
    <flow:interview name="My_First_Flow_New_Primary_Contact"
                    finishLocation="{!URLENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.vOpportunityId)}">
        </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

But it gives this error

***Invalid Page Redirection
The page you attempted to access has been blocked due to a redirection to an outside website or an improperly coded link or button. Please contact your salesforce.com Administrator for assistance. 
Click here to return to the previous page.***

Is there anyway round this error message?

The following works fine from a custom button, but read retURL is unreliable.

```
https://eu3.salesforce.com/flow/My_First_Flow_New_Primary_Contact?vAccountId={!Opportunity.AccountId}&vOpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}
```

I would have thought directing should be handled in the flow entirely - have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Got it this time.

Change the button to open the VisualForce page and then use this

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
<flow:interview name="My_First_Flow_New_Primary_Contact"
                finishLocation="/{!Opportunity.Id}">
                  <apex:param name="vAccountId" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}"/>
                  <apex:param name="vOpportunityId" value="{!Opportunity.Id}"/>

    </flow:interview>
```